# detect color temperature settings of display?

Tags: colors, monitor, web, temperature

is it possible to detect the color temperature settings of a monitor or display with css, javascript, html5, silverlight, java, flash, or anything that could be used on the web?

no problem if it's not working for all the cases, I am interested in everything.

if it is not possible right now at all, is there work in progress for this field (under what name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't any way to detect this from web-based tools. In fact, there isn't really any way to detect this (in general) from a computer at all. You can change your monitor's settings all you like and your computer never knows the difference. It just sends the video signal down the cord and doesn't really care what the monitor does with it.

There is *some* information that goes back from the monitor to the computer, but in general color temperature is not included in that information.

However, some platforms that are more integrated, like many Apple products, *may* have a way to get this information from the system, but it would likely need to be a native application that has access to low-level system APIs, which most frameworks (especially web ones), including those you mentioned, tend not to have access to.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is a sad thing to hear. I hope one day it will be realized how great this would be.

Comment: ah! sure! :D was it in 2011?... anyway, thanks and here is the upvote ^_^